# Camel: How to once insert data into DB table if only all xmls are valid?

Tags: java, apache-camel

Collegues, i have the route which validate xml over xsd. I this case the route call `.to("jdbc:DataSource")` every time when any xml is valid:

```
 from("ftp://....." +
            "&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true" +
            "&filterDirectory=${date:now:yyyymmdd}")
                .choice() 
                  .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("XML_A.....")).log("Validate ${file:name}")
                     .to("validator:file:C:\\integration\\xsds\\xml_a.xsd").log("${file:name} is valid")
                  .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("XML_B.....")).log("Validate ${file:name}")
                     .to("validator:file:C:\\integration\\xsds\\xml_b.xsd").log("${file:name} is valid")
                 .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("XML_C.....")).log("Validate ${file:name}")
                     .to("validator:file:C:\\integration\\xsds\\xml_c.xsd").log("${file:name} is valid") 
               .end()
               .log("Upload table ExtractS") 
               .to("bean:stgExtractToSQL")
               .to("jdbc:dataSource") /*Here i would like to execute only one insert into one single table*/
            ;
```

How call `.to("jdbc:dataSource")` only one time (only) when all xml are valid?
P.S.
After `.to("jdbc:dataSource")` i need to process every xml file.
Thank you.

Comment: How do you specify `when all xml valid`? If on the FTP server only 3 files you distinguish this case from the case with 5 files?

Comment: Consider the fact that each file will spawn a separate thread. You would have to store the state somehow and then only call the database when the predicate is fulfilled. Perhaps you should take a look at claim-check EIP http://camel.apache.org/claim-check.html

Comment: Collegues, is there any way to execute insert once before route start? It seems suitable for me too.

Comment: That depends on the requirements. You could create a separate route for the database insert and use a timer to initiate the route. Say that you want to poll the ftp every 30 seconds then you could have your database-route run every 20/25 seconds. Another possibility could be to utilize the enrichment EIP http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html. That way you could first make your insert and then use poll-enrich to fetch your files within the same route.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a validation error, Camel's validator component will throw an exceptions, so you shouldn't get to `.to("jdbc:dataSource")` and should be safe. However, a better way to handle this is to use a `doTry()` and `doCatch()` in your route to indicate that it's aware of the exception and in case you need to add additional behavior when validation fails. So your route would look something like the following:

```
from("ftp://....." +
        "&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true" +
        "&filterDirectory=${date:now:yyyymmdd}")
            .log("Validate ${file:name}")
            .doTry()
              .choice() 
                .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("XML_A....."))
                  .to("validator:file:C:\\integration\\xsds\\xml_a.xsd")
                .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("XML_B....."))
                  .to("validator:file:C:\\integration\\xsds\\xml_b.xsd")
               .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("XML_C....."))
                  .to("validator:file:C:\\integration\\xsds\\xml_c.xsd") 
             .endChoice()

             .log("${file:name} is valid")
             .log("Upload table ExtractS") 
             .to("bean:stgExtractToSQL")
             .to("jdbc:dataSource") /*Here i would like to execute only one insert into one single table*/
           .endDoTry()
           .doCatch(ValidationException.class)
             .log("Validation of file [${file:name}] failed")
           .end()
        ;
```

Comment: Khaled, i think this route wil call `.to("bean:stgExtractToSQL")` every time when the current xml will be valid, but i need to call `.to("bean:stgExtractToSQL")` only one time  when all xml are valid.

Comment: So you're passing in several xml files? If so, how do you  know that they have all gone through the validator route? Is it a set number of file per some unit of time?